# No edit button in the software center

Tags: software-center

- Go to Ubuntu Software Center.
- Edit > Software Sources
- Change the server from the default value to some other value.

I couldn't find the edit button under the Ubuntu software center.

Answer (score 5):

You have to go on the menu bar (black stripe on the top of the screen) and hover the mouse there. Menus will appear, including "Edit".

You can also modify the software sources by going to the update manager and then go to  "Settings", the button on the bottom left. Once there you will be asked the password to proceed.

[image]

Place your mouse there at black color marked area , you will get menu . Hope that helps .

Comment: A screenshot here would be great!

Comment: Yes, but I've menus in Italian. It would be nice if somebody with an English layout could do it and edit the question. I think, it's better for the user (given the level).

Comment: ok I have added :D

Comment: +1 for the small sized screenshot. Those are really helpful for the users with low bandwidth or monthly limit.

Answer (score 1):

Just a little more info on this. I came here looking for the same information, but hover as I might, I could not make the File/Edit/View/Help buttons appear until I did one of 2 things.

As someone previously stated, you can maximize the Ubuntu Software centre window and then mouse over the top strip of the window, OR, if the window is not maximized, you can hover the mouse over the top strip on the screen (the one with the time, speaker icon etc. on the left side)

[I don't have enough rep to embed a photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BWJd.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can change your server from update manager also . Open you update manager -> Settings then Ubuntu software TAB look at the image . [image]

Answer (score 0):

Well the same happened with me when I installed salamander, but the easiest thing I think would be to just maximize the window, ie, the software center window. That way, the options appear.